# Railsでネストされたモデルの名前を日本語で表示させたい (i18n)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

formで値が不正だったときに表示されるエラーメッセージのモデル名を日本語にする方法が分かりません。

```
class Ranking < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ranking_posts, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ranking_posts
  validates_associated :ranking_posts
end
```

と

```
class RankingPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ranking
  default_scope -> { order('rank DESC') }
  validates :title, :description, :rank, presence: true
end
```

として、RankingとRankingPostを同時に更新出来るformを作成しました。
そしてRankingPost側を不正な値でformを送信すると、エラーメッセージで「Ranking postsは不正な値です。」と表示されます。この「Ranking posts」を日本語にする方法を知りたいです。

i18nで

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      ranking/ranking_posts: すべてのランキング記事
```

のようにしても適用されませんでした。
どのような方法でネストされたモデル名を日本語化できるか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ranking`モデルの`ranking_posts`属性の名前なので、`activerecord.models`ではなく`activerecord.attributes`以下に設定を書くとよいと思います。以下のような感じです。

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      ranking:
        ranking_posts: すべてのランキング記事
```

http://railsguides.jp/i18n.html の4.6あたりです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。出来ました！
　accepts_nested_attributes_forを使うと、i18nではmodelsからattributesへ変わるといった認識であってますでしょうか？